# How to manipulate my audit item to persist in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, audit

I'm using Spring Boot and JpaRepository to persist my datas. But I need a way to audit my jpa requests.

The problem is. I wanna get the event generated in the moment of the request happened and get the object to persist and the old object and manipulate it to persist in a custom audit table. I don't wanna use the default structure to audit. For example @JaversSpringDataAuditable persist the audit in a specific structure of tables. I don't wanna this I just wanna get the structure in a interceptor or something like this and manipulate it to persist my specific structure

Answer (score 0):

It is not that clear what exactly you want to achieve. Therefore, I will mention some easy ways of auditing in Spring Boot which hopefully help.

For auditing JPA interactions, you can enable the JPA auditing width the annotation `@EnableJpaAuditing` in a `@Config` class. You can make an entity auditable with the annotation `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)`. The audit information will then be captured when an entity object gets persisted or updated.

Such an annotated entity can for example store the `@CreatedDate` or `@LastModifiedDate`. For more information, you can have a look in [the documentation of Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.0.DATAJPA-580-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/auditing.html).

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class ExampleEntity {
    
    //...
    
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @CreatedDate
    private long createdDate;

    @Column(name = "modified_date")
    @LastModifiedDate
    private long modifiedDate;
    
    //...
}
```

If you want to execute some actions before an entity is persisted or updated, you can use the annotations `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` (`@PreRemove` is also available but does not seem to be needed).

```
@Entity
public class Example Entity {

    //...
      
    @PrePersist
    public void onPrePersist() { 
        // Do something before entity is persisted
    }
      
    @PreUpdate
    public void onPreUpdate() { 
        // Do something before entity is updated
    }
}
```